Why I am getting MLE(memory limit exceded) in hackerearth platform
If you don't knew solution leave it some other will give answer but don't put negetive voting.
t = int(input())

for i in range(t):
    x,l,n = map(int, input().split())
    for xi in range(x,-1,-1):
        if xi*(2**(n-1))<=l:
            print(x-xi)
            break

Above is my program for the inputs of
1
1000000000000000000 0 1000000000000000000

I am getting MLE. I didn't understand. but in hackerearth they mention we can use upto 256mb.
If I run same logic in c++ it is working fine.
I am expecting it to run without any errors.
Problem if any one want the question -
Kate is wizard. Now she should pass the exam.
During the exam she have to go into the magic room N times. Initially there are X magic items in the room. Before each visit she can use magic to decrease the number of magic items in the room. For each item she spends 1 mana point to destroy it. After each visit the number of magic items increases by 2 times. She can't go into room if there are more than L magic items in it. What minimum mana points does Kate need to pass the exam?
You need to solve this problem for several test cases.
Those who think I was wrong please open this image I completed 200+ problems in leetcode not seen this kind of error

I updated picture also check it. Its python 3 and its showing MLE

You're trying to calculate 2**999999999999999999, which can't be good...


t = int(input())

for i in range(t):
    x,l,n = map(int, input().split())
    if n>60:
        print(x)
    elif n==0:
        print(0)
    else:
        for xi in range(x,-1,-1):
            if xi*(2**(n-1))<=l:
                print(x-xi)
                break


I am calculating 2**9999999999999999 which is taking lots of memory. So I used condition to check the value till 60 only. I came to number 60 based on given constarints in the question. I understood this mistake by the comments on this question.
Thank for helping guys... :)
